# where not in / where not like subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Can somebody help me out with a MS-SQL query please.

I have the following:

```
select Name from Keyword.dbo.NGrams
where Name not in (select Name from Keyword.dbo.Brands)
```

What I really want is something like this, but I can't get the syntax right

```
select Name from Keyword.dbo.NGrams
where Name not like (select Name from Keyword.dbo.Brands)
```

"not in" works great for NGrams & Brands that match exactly. But my NGrams are multiple words long and some contain a Brand within them.

Thanks so much

Edit: Maybe I can re-clarify what I am looking for my this pseudo sql:

select Name from Keyword.dbo.NGrams
    where Description not containing (select Word from Keyword.dbo.Brands)

Brand is a list of single words. Description in NGrams would be a 2 or 3 word phrase. I want to select all the NGrams that do not contain any of the Brands

Comment: Can you show how your data looks, it would be easy to figure out.

Comment: Brand.Name would be something like "Nike". And NGram.Name would be something like "Green Nike Shoes".

Comment: Try getting all the matched name in one temp table and compare your same query with temp table. it should work just fine.

Comment: Do you want NGrams like: "indigestion dysPEPSIa" to be filtered out?

Comment: No only whole words would be necessary

Comment: I've edited the question to further clarify what I am trying to do

Comment: Why don't you just use the fulltext index? You don't have to care about 'normalized word lists' etc. Just have your text in one (or more) columns, generate the index and start exploring the extremely powerful world of full text indexes.

Comment: I have never used a fulltext index. Would I create it on the NGram table? And then how would I express my second pseudo query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  n.Name
FROM Keyword.dbo.NGrams n
LEFT JOIN Keyword.dbo.Brands b
  ON n.Name LIKE '%'+b.Name+'%'
WHERE b.Name IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d889/1)

If you want to avoid the [Scunthorpe Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) and only match whole words, change the join condition to:

```
  ON ' '+n.Name+' ' LIKE '% '+b.Name+' %'
```

Comment: Minor issue with this is that the join can potentially duplicate names from Keyword.dbo.NGrams n where the LIKE satisfies multiple names.

Comment: @KRichard in the SQL Fiddle example there are NGrams that match multiple Brands.  The output has no duplicates.  Do you have sample data that produces duplicates?

Comment: @Anon Yes, you are correct. I was focused on the join, which I think could return dups, but any matching dups would be eliminated by the WHERE b.Name IS NULL

Comment: @Anon Shouldn't it be NOT LIKE as per the OP requirement?

Comment: @IndoKnight no, it shouldn't.  Play with the SQL Fiddle example a bit to see why.

Comment: Busy running this as a test (without an index). 24 minutes so far. The "not in" runs in 4 seconds.

Comment: Still waiting. Almost two hours have passed.

Comment: Nothing else is running on the server, just this one query

Comment: @Trevor FYI, a like that starts with a '%' can't use an index - that's probably why this is so much slower than the `not in`. You can look into full text indexes, or use the other option by Anon to get around this

Comment: This took 4 hours to run, and did not work. My "not in" query produced 280 000 rows, but your query produced 544.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test using the ENABLE2K standard English word list.  I generated 10 million random ngrams and 50000 random brands.  The query takes about 1 minute to run on my workstation.

```
CREATE TABLE #enable2k (word varchar(max) NOT NULL)
BULK INSERT #enable2k FROM 'C:\enable2k.txt'

CREATE TABLE #ngrams (ngram_id int NOT NULL, word_num int NOT NULL, word varchar(max) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(ngram_id, word_num));
INSERT #ngrams SELECT TOP 10000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()), 1, word FROM #enable2k,(SELECT TOP 58 0 FROM master..spt_values) t(i)
INSERT #ngrams SELECT TOP 10000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()), 2, word FROM #enable2k,(SELECT TOP 58 0 FROM master..spt_values) t(i)
INSERT #ngrams SELECT TOP 10000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()), 3, word FROM #enable2k,(SELECT TOP 58 0 FROM master..spt_values) t(i)

CREATE TABLE #brands (brand varchar(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT #brands SELECT TOP 50000 word FROM #enable2k WHERE LEN(word) <= 32 ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT *
FROM #ngrams n
PIVOT (MIN(word) FOR word_num IN ([1],[2],[3])) n1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM #ngrams n2
  INNER JOIN #brands b
    ON (n2.word = b.brand)
  WHERE n1.ngram_id = n2.ngram_id
)
```

Comment: Hmmm, this looks interesting because I already have the NGrams normalized. Let me give this a go!

Comment: No luck with this. I get the same number of results with and without the where not exists. I don't really understand the sql well enough to understand why

Comment: Post your actual schema and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where not exists` to express the like:

```
select Name 
from Keyword.dbo.NGrams ng
where not exists (
    select *
    from Keyword.dbo.Brands b
    where ng.Name like '%' + b.name + '%'
)
```

Comment: This query is also reducing my returned results from 280 000 to 544 which is also not correct. But it ran much quicker than the first solution. 37 mins versus 4 hours

Comment: @Trevor If two different solutions to your question produce the the exact same number of results and you reject both, maybe you are asking the wrong question.